# Filter between two input dates on html table - Java script

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to filter on my html table by inputting two dates(From and To) and then it should filter the data in the html table column[0] "Date Column" accordingly.

The inputs on my page::

`<input type="date" id="date-start" onselect="searchDate()" />`

`<input type="date" id="date-stop" onselect="searchDate()" />`

The java script I have together so far is:

```
    function searchDate() {
        var input_startDate, input_stopDate, table, tr, i;
        input_startDate = document.getElementById("date-start");
        input_stopDate = document.getElementById("date-stop");
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td_date = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

            if (td_date) {

                if (td_date >= input_startDate && td_name <= input_stopDate) {
                    ??? - Display Rows;
                }
                else {
                    ??? - Hide Rows;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know this might be pretty straight forward but I have no idea what to do as I can't seem to get it working.

My table gets created as follows:

```
        @if (employees is null)
    {
        <p style="color:white;"><em>Loading . . .</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        <table class="table" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="border: none;">Entry Date</th>
                    <th style="border: none;">Employee</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var employee in employees)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border: none;">@employee.EntryDate</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border: none;">@employee.POI</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Database format is: 2020-06-05 10:57:10

Thanks.

Comment: firstly we need to see your date format. then you need to convert your html to date and compare this dates

Comment: @pc My tables date format "2020-06-05 10:57:10" as it is in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple issues in the sample:

1. you are not getting the actual values from the table td cells or
   inputs
2. you need to convert the values to dates to compare
   correctly
3. you can then hide/show a row by setting the display
   property on the style

See the commented demo below:

```js
function searchDate() {
  var input_startDate, input_stopDate, table, tr, i;

  // get the values and convert to date
  input_startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("date-start").value);
  input_stopDate = new Date(document.getElementById("date-stop").value);

  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    // you need to get the text and convert to date
    let td_date = new Date(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0].textContent);

    // now you can compare dates correctly
    if (td_date) {
      if (td_date >= input_startDate && td_date <= input_stopDate) {
        // show the row by setting the display property
        tr[i].style.display = 'table-row;';
      } else {
        // hide the row by setting the display property
        tr[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

  }
}

function searchDateAlternative() {
  // get the values and convert to date
  const input_startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("date-start").value);
  const input_stopDate = new Date(document.getElementById("date-stop").value);

  // only process table body rows, ignoring footer/headers
  const tr = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr")

  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    // ensure we have a relevant td
    let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    if (!td || !td[0]) continue;

    // you need to get the text and convert to date
    let td_date = new Date(td[0].textContent);

    // now you can compare dates correctly
    if (td_date) {
      if (td_date >= input_startDate && td_date <= input_stopDate) {
        // show the row by setting the display property
        tr[i].style.display = 'table-row;';
      } else {
        // hide the row by setting the display property
        tr[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```css
#myTable td {
 border: 1px solid;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<input id="date-start" type="text" value="2020-01-01"></input>
<input id="date-stop" type="text" value="2020-01-02"></input>
<button type="button" onclick="searchDateAlternative()">Go</button>
<hr/>
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2020-01-01</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2020-01-02</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2020-01-03</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How you guys get to be so quick and smart. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay so although your snippet works, it seems as though when I apply this to my stuff I get the following error: 

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
    at searchDate
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (<anonymous>:2:1)**

Checked through F12 developer on website.

Any ideas?

Comment: sound like you have a row without a `td` in it. I updated the snippet to an example of how to check you have an appropriate `td` to operate on -- in a nutshell, make sure the table schema is correct for your operation

Comment: PS, daardie hond is nie 'n braak nie

Comment: lol, 'n brakkie... Anyways die filter werk nou maar sodra filter apply dan sit hy my ander columns nou in my date column in.

Comment: yeah oversight on my part - set `display: table-row;` not `display: block` so you keep the formatting

Comment: Your code seems working just once?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style.display` to hide/show your rows. Set it to 'none' to hide the rows or 'block' to view them.

```
function searchDate() {
    var input_startDate, input_stopDate, table, tr, i;
    input_startDate = document.getElementById("date-start");
    input_stopDate = document.getElementById("date-stop");
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td_date = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

        if (td_date) {

            if (td_date >= input_startDate && td_name <= input_stopDate) {
                tr[i].style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also add a custom class to visible elements and alter use it for transitions or animations. I generally prefer adding a class to elements I have to hide and adding a 0.5-second transition of them greying out and hiding