# Filter the data between two dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to filter the table rows between the start date and end date on clicking the button but I don't know where I'm wrong I just got this snippet from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268776/filter-between-two-input-dates-on-html-table-java-script),but it didn't worked for me.

I'm new to JS I'm trying to implement this part in the code but it didn't I couldn't able to find what's going wrong and my html input calendar is in mm/dd/yyyy format and my table date which comes from an api in yyyy-mm-dd format. thanks in advance

```js
function searchDate() {
  var input_startDate, input_stopDate, table, tr, i;
  // get the values and convert to date
  input_startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("from_date").value);
  input_stopDate = new Date(document.getElementById("To_date").value);

  table = document.getElementById("table_id");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    // you need to get the text and convert to date
    let td_date = new Date(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td").textContent);

    // now you can compare dates correctly
    if (td_date) {
      if (td_date >= input_startDate && td_date <= input_stopDate) {
        // show the row by setting the display property
        tr[i].style.display = 'table-row;';
      } else {
        // hide the row by setting the display property
        tr[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }

  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="margin-left: 19px; font-size: 17px;">NetDue Date</div>
<div class="row" id="id_row">

  <div class='row' style="margin-left: 19px;"> From:</div>
  <input type="date" name="from_Date" style="margin-left: 30px; font-size: 20px;" placeholder="From_Date" id="From_Date" required="">
  <div class='row' style="margin-left: 19px;"> To:</div>
  <input type="date" name="to_Date" style="margin-left: 30px;font-size: 20px;" placeholder="To_Date" id="To_Date" required="">
  <input type="submit" value="Apply" id="btn_submit" style=" width:90px; 
                height:45px; margin-left: 40px; margin-bottom: 30px;" class="btn btn-success btn" onclick="searchDate()">

  <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="btn_submit" style=" width:90px; 
           height:45px;margin-left: 65px; margin-bottom: 30px;" class="btn btn-success btn">
</div>

<table class="table table-striped border datatable" id='table_id'>
  <!-- <table class="dataclass" id='table_id'>  -->
  <thead>
    <thead id="tablehead">
      <tr>
        <th> Region</th>
        <th> Area </th>
        <th> Date </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> US</td>
        <td> NorthAmerica</td>
        <td> 2021-27-10
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> US</td>
        <td> NorthAmerica</td>
        <td> 2021-26-10
          <td>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following HTML and JS Code,
I hope this will full fill your expectations

**JS CODE**

```
function searchDate() {
    var input_startDate, input_stopDate, tr, i;
  // get the values and convert to date
  input_startDate =  new Date(document.getElementById("From_Date").value);
  input_stopDate =  new Date(document.getElementById("To_Date").value);

  tr = document.querySelectorAll("#table_id tbody tr");

  for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    // ensure we have a relevant td
    let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    if (!td || !td[2]) continue;

    // you need to get the text and convert to date
    let td_date = new Date(td[2].textContent);
    

    // now you can compare dates correctly
    if (td_date) {
      if (td_date >= input_startDate && td_date <= input_stopDate) {
        // show the row by setting the display property
        tr[i].style.display = 'table-row;';
      } else {
        // hide the row by setting the display property
        tr[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div style="margin-left: 19px; font-size: 17px;">NetDue Date</div>
<div class="row" id="id_row">
   <div class='row' style="margin-left: 19px;"> From:</div>
   <input type="date" name="from_Date"  style="margin-left: 30px; font-size: 20px;" 
      placeholder="From_Date" id="From_Date" required="" > 
   <div class='row' style="margin-left: 19px;">  To:</div>
   <input type="date" name="to_Date" style="margin-left: 30px;font-size: 20px;" 
      placeholder="To_Date" id="To_Date" required="" > 
   <input type="submit" value="Apply" id="btn_submit" style=" width:90px; 
      height:45px; margin-left: 40px; margin-bottom: 30px;"
      class="btn btn-success btn" onclick="searchDate()">
   <input type="reset" value="Reset" id="btn_submit" style=" width:90px; 
      height:45px;margin-left: 65px; margin-bottom: 30px;"
      class="btn btn-success btn">
</div>
<table class="table table-striped border datatable" id='table_id'>
  <!-- <table class="dataclass" id='table_id'>  -->
  <thead id="tablehead">
      <tr>
         <th>Region</th>
         <th>Area</th>
         <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>US</td>
         <td>NorthAmerica</td>
         <td>2021-10-27</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>US</td>
         <td>NorthAmerica</td>
         <td>2021-10-26</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**WORKING FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/katheer_mizal/dpfa0Lw6/49/

**----------------------------------------------------**

**I have done 5 code changes in you given code**

**1st** mistake in ids' passed to getElementById function

```
input_startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("from_date").value);
input_stopDate = new Date(document.getElementById("To_date").value);
```

changed to

```
input_startDate =  new Date(document.getElementById("From_Date").value);
input_stopDate =  new Date(document.getElementById("To_Date").value);
```

---

**2nd** Update variable assigns

```
var input_startDate, input_stopDate, table, tr, i;
```

Changed to

```
var input_startDate, input_stopDate, tr, i;
```

---

**3rd** change table, and tr variable assign

```
table = document.getElementById("table_id");
tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
```

changed to

```
tr = document.querySelectorAll("#table_id tbody tr");
```

---

**4th**  for loop go changed

```
for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  // you need to get the text and convert to date
  let td_date = new Date(tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td").textContent);

  // now you can compare dates correctly
  if (td_date) {
    if (td_date >= input_startDate && td_date <= input_stopDate) {
      // show the row by setting the display property
      tr[i].style.display = 'table-row;';
    } else {
      // hide the row by setting the display property
      tr[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

changed to

```
for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
  // ensure we have a relevant td
  let td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
  if (!td || !td[2]) continue;

  // you need to get the text and convert to date
  let td_date = new Date(td[2].textContent);

  // now you can compare dates correctly
  if (td_date) {
    if (td_date >= input_startDate && td_date <= input_stopDate) {
      // show the row by setting the display property
      tr[i].style.display = 'table-row;';
    } else {
      // hide the row by setting the display property
      tr[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

---

**5th** date format got changed in given table

- your using date input type (input[type="date"])
- date input type giving date output format is yyyy-mm-dd (2021-10-26), more details check this link [Click Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)
- but your using data format is yyyy-dd-mm (2021-26-10)
- so I changed all date values into yyyy-mm-dd (2021-10-26) format

```
<table class="table table-striped border datatable" id='table_id'>
   <!-- <table class="dataclass" id='table_id'>  -->
   <thead>
   <thead id="tablehead">
      <tr>
         <th> Region</th>
         <th> Area </th>
         <th> Date </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> US</td>
         <td> NorthAmerica</td>
         <td> 2021-27-10
         <td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> US</td>
         <td> NorthAmerica</td>
         <td> 2021-26-10
         <td>
      </tr>
   <tbody>
</table>
```

Changed to

```
<table class="table table-striped border datatable" id='table_id'>
  <!-- <table class="dataclass" id='table_id'>  -->
  <thead id="tablehead">
      <tr>
         <th>Region</th>
         <th>Area</th>
         <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>US</td>
         <td>NorthAmerica</td>
         <td>2021-10-27</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>US</td>
         <td>NorthAmerica</td>
         <td>2021-10-26</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you @Katheer,  but date format which I mention in the table which comes from the API which I shouldn't change. Is there any way that I can change the html date format

Comment: @imran_44 if you try to convert your API providing value into Date object, it'll throgh the error. So we have to write some custom code to format your API providing value. According to that I have created the custme function to convert your API providing value, please check following JS fiddle for more details https://jsfiddle.net/katheer_mizal/dpfa0Lw6/191/

Comment: Thanks Katheer for ur efforts, I will try this out

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in ids' passed to getElementById function.
Change the following 
From

```
input_startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("from_date").value);
input_stopDate = new Date(document.getElementById("To_date").value);
```

to

```
input_startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("From_Date").value);
input_stopDate = new Date(document.getElementById("To_Date").value);
```